# Execution time for a SQL Query seems excessive

Tags: sql-server

I have a data set of about 33 million rows and 20 columns. One of the columns is a raw data tab I'm using to extract relevant data from, inlcuding ID's and account numbers.

I extracted a column for User ID's into a temporary table to trim the User ID's of spaces. I'm now trying to add the trimmed User ID column back into the original data set using this code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[DATA] AS A
INNER JOIN #TempTable AS B ON A. [RawColumn] = B. [RawColumn]
```

Extracting the User ID's and trimming the spaces took about a minute for each query. However, running this last query I'm at the 2 hour mark and I'm only 2% of the way through the dataset.

Is there a better way to run the query?

I'm running the query in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Thanks

***Update:***

I continued to let it run through the night. When I got back into work, only 6 million rows had been completed of the 33 million rows. I cancelled the execution and I'm trying to add a smaller primary key (The only other key I could see on the table was the [RawColumn], which was a very long string of text) using:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DATA]
ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Right now I'm an hour into the execution.
Next, I'm planning to make it the primary key using

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[DATA]
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_[DATA] PRIMARY KEY(ID)
```

I'm not familiar with using Indexes.. I've tried looking up on Stack Overflow how to create one, but from what I'm reading it sounds like it would take just as long to create an index as it would to run this query. Am I wrong about that?

For context on the RawColumn data, it looks something like this:

```
FirstName: John   LastName: Smith     UserID: JohnS   Account#: 000-000-0000
```

***Update #2:***

I'm now learning that using "ALTER TABLE" is a bad idea. I should have done a little bit more research into how to add a primary key to a table.

***Update #3***

Here's the code I used to extract the "UserID" code out of the "RawColumn" data.

```
DROP #TEMPTABLE1
GO
SELECT [RAWColumn],
SUBSTRING([RAWColumn], CHARINDEX('USERID:', [RAWColumn])+LEN('USERID:'), CHARINDEX('Account#:', [RAWColumn])-Charindex('Username:', [RAWColumn]) - LEN('Account#:') - LEN('USERID:')) AS 'USERID_NEW'
INTO #TempTable1
FROM [dbo].[DATA]
```

Next I trimmed the data from the temporary tables

```
DROP #TEMPTABLE2
GO
SELECT [RawColumn],
LTRIM([USERID_NEW]) AS 'USERID_NEW'
INTO #TempTable2
FROM #TempTable1
```

So now I'm trying to get the data from #TEMPTABLE2 back into my original [DATA] table. Hopefully this is more clear now.

Comment: perform the update in batches....

Comment: have you create indexes? try to use Where clause

Comment: Did you create an index on the #temptable? How big is the RawColumn? Is there a better integer key you could use?

Comment: When you created the #TempTable, is the RawColumn column same datatype as your [DATA] table? And I mean absolutely the same? And why do you need to extract UserID's of spaces separately? You can do it in the SELECT statement.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: is there primary key on table DATA? if not could you create new identity column and inner join on that column?

Comment: You said you were "add(ing) the trimmed User ID column back into the original data", but your code was just a SELECT statement. What are you actually trying to do with your DATA table? Your problem may be that you're taking the wrong approach, but we won't really know that without knowing what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: So, I'm trying to get the "UserID" out of the "RawColumn" field. I'll post the code I used to extract it.

Comment: But what are you trying to do after you extract the UserID? Is this part of a stored procedure? are you wanting to store the UserID in another column in your [DATA] table? What final output are you trying to achieve? Or what business logic are you trying to implement?

Comment: Ah ok, so the [DATA] tab already has a USERID column, but it's filled with mistakes from when the data was originally uploaded. Instead of USERID being "JSMITH" like in the above example, we have USERIDs like "ID: JSMITH", or "D: JSMITH".   I'm not sure what the end goal is, but my task was just to clean up the "USERID" field. We have several other data tables with comparable USERID's to connect the data table. Because the USERID's in this table are incorrect, we can't properly match them. To me, it seemed the best way was to start with the "RAW" tab and correctly grab the information.

Comment: So, yes. I'm wanting to store the UserID in another column in my Data Table. That's my final goal.

Comment: Why not just do all of this in one UPDATE statement to clean this up (or write out the full set to a new table). `UPDATE [dbo].[data] SET [rawdata] = SUBSTRING([RAWColumn], CHARINDEX('USERID:', [RAWColumn])+LEN('USERID:'), CHARINDEX('Account#:', [RAWColumn])-Charindex('Username:', [RAWColumn]) - LEN('Account#:') - LEN('USERID:'));`  Then you don't have to screw around with joining on a really ugly column. If that is not a solution then you should have also extracted the primary key from the `[dbo].[data]` table into your #temptable1 to be used in your join at the end.

Comment: @JNevill beat me to my answer.

Comment: Ultimately I think you want to 100% avoid using `[rawdata]` as your join condition. It's a big ugly expensive field and I can't imagine it's the primary key on your table. It would also be expensive as an index (and probably not helpful as I'm betting it's pretty distinct).

Answer (score 0):

So I think your parsing code is a little bit wrong. Here's an approach that doesn't assume that the values appear in any particular order. It does assume that the header/tag name has a space after the colon character and it assumes that the value end at the subsequent space character. Here's a snippet that manipulates a single value.

```
declare @dat varchar(128) = 'FirstName: John   LastName: Smith     UserID: JohnS   Account#: 000-000-0000';
declare @tag varchar(16) = 'UserID: ';

/* datalength() counts the trailing space character unlike len() */
declare @idx int = charindex(@tag, @dat) + datalength(@tag);
select substring(@dat, @idx, charindex(' ', @dat + ' ', @idx + 1) - @idx) as UserID
```

To use it in a single query without the temporary variable, the most straightforward approach is to just replace each instance of "@idx" with the original expression:

```
declare @tag varchar(16) = 'UserID: ';
select RawColumn,
    substring(
        RawColumn,
        charindex(@tag, RawColumn) + datalength(@tag),
        charindex(
            ' ',  RawColumn + ' ',
            charindex(@tag, RawColumn) + datalength(@tag) + 1
        ) - charindex(@tag, RawColumn) + datalength(@tag)
    ) as UserID
from dbo.DATA;
```

As an `update` it looks something like this:

```
declare @tag varchar(16) = 'UserID: ';
update dbo.DATA
set UserID = 
    substring(
        RawColumn,
        charindex(@tag, RawColumn) + datalength(@tag),
        charindex(
            ' ',  RawColumn + ' ',
            charindex(@tag, RawColumn) + datalength(@tag) + 1
        ) - charindex(@tag, RawColumn) + datalength(@tag)
    ) as UserID;
```

You also appear to be ignoring upper/lower case in your string matches. It's not clear to me whether you need to consider that more carefully.